# Android NDK can't find native function

Tags: android, android-ndk

Java code :

```
package com.example.maxim.myapplication;

//...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    public native String  stringFromJNI();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
        }


}
```

C code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>


    jstring Java_com_example_maxim_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                      jobject thiz )
    {


        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI .");
    }
```

LogCat output:

```
 Process: com.example.maxim.myapplication, PID: 2306
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.maxim.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI() (tried Java_com_example_maxim_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI and Java_com_example_maxim_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI__)
            at com.example.maxim.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI(Native Method)
 ....
```

The package name is the same as the name of the function, but there is an errorThe package name is the same as the name of the function, but there is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare you native method within your shared object like this

```
JNIEXPORT jstring Java_com_example_maxim_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

The key point is the `JNIEXPORT` which instrucs the linker/compiler exposing/exporting your native method

EDIT - You also want make sure that indeed the "correct" `so` (libhello-jni.so) is being loaded (in the sense that indeed this `so` contains your method implementation, maybe you got some stale `so` somewhere in your library path)

Add debug `logcat` to your `so` upon its very loading

```
jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{

    LOGI("In JNI_OnLoad()");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6; // or the version corresponded to your NDK version
}
```

Comment: @Hemul if this is the case, make sure that indeed the so object which contains the method implementation is being loaded, see my edit to the answer